# Using C#, how can I access the ViewModel's properties and methods when used as a static resource?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel

I have ViewModels instantiated as a Static Resource in App.xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileApp.App"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MobileApp.ViewModels">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ViewModels:MerchandiserViewModel x:Key="MerchandiserViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I would like to be able to access the properties of the ViewModel in C#

e.g.

```
string MerchandiserName = "Reference to Static Resource "MerchandiserViewModel.Name" Property Here";
```

Comment: You don't, at least not in MVVM. MVVM decouples the view and its data (the viewmodel). What you're trying to achieve violates MVVM principles. This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: That XY problem link was great by the way.  I will re-evaluate my problem and update accordingly.

Comment: This was actually a thought to another question I posted.  For context see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67155820/should-viewmodels-inherit-other-viewmodels-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Aside from XY Problem link (which is good), as it states, step back a moment.  You keep mentioning STATIC in this class, and in the other question you posted.  Please edit your existing question.  Can you elaborate on what pieces you are referring are "Static" and why?  Is this supposed to be some global properties within your app?  Should it be a singleton instance you are grabbing settings from used globally you want exposure to?  Please clarify what you are trying to get from it and apply better context.

Comment: Thanks DRapp, when I mention `Static Resource` I am referring to resources stored in a `App.xaml` resource dictionary.

I want to reference/inherit each `ViewModel` with a single instance of a global ViewModel that contains a property to an `SelectedItem` from a  `ListView`

 The problem I am having is I need to keep track of which item (or Merchandiser in my case) was selected so that each ViewModel can display bindings specific to that selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create MerchandiserViewModel class, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify data changed.

```
 public class MerchandiserViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _str;
    public string str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("str");
        }
    }
    public ICommand command1 { get; set; }    
         
    public MerchandiserViewModel()
    {
        str = "test";
        command1 = new Command(()=> {

            Console.WriteLine("this is test!!!!!!!");
        });
    }
}
```

Adding in APP.xaml as static resource.

```
<Application
x:Class="FormsSample.App"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:FormsSample.simplecontrol"
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:FormsSample.resourcedictionary">
<Application.Resources>
    
    <models:MerchandiserViewModel x:Key="model1" />
</Application.Resources>
```

You can get properties and command from viewmodel in every contentpage.cs.

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MerchandiserViewModel viewmodel = (MerchandiserViewModel)Application.Current.Resources["model1"];
        string value1= viewmodel.str;

        ICommand command = viewmodel.command1;
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cherry, I'll use this as the accepted answer as it technically answers the question.  However, as previously indicated by others my problem is a bit deeper than I first thought and I may need to relook at the problem for the best solution.