# How can I edit and delete a ListView SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I want to create an application that can Create, Read, Update and Delete Merchandiser records.
I am struggling with how to "Update" and "Delete" a record based on a `ItemSelected` in the `ListView`.

The item selected in the `ListView` represents a `Merchandiser` and is currently being passed into each new `View` as an argument.

I intend to store data in an SQLite database, but for simplicity have not included any of that logic.  Database `Commands` (Save, Delete etc.) will be created in the `MerchandiserViewModel`

Here is my slimmed down code so far

**Merchandiser.cs** Model

```
 public class Merchandiser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
    // Additional Properties not shown for simplicity
}
```

**MerchandiserViewModel.cs** ViewModel

```
    public class MerchandiserViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Merchandiser> MerchandiserList { get; set; }

        private Merchandiser selectedItem;
        public Merchandiser SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MerchandiserViewModel()
        {
            MerchandiserList = new ObservableCollection<Merchandiser>();

            CreateData();
        }

        private void CreateData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Merchandiser merchandiser = new Merchandiser();
                merchandiser.Name = $"Merchandiser {i}";
                merchandiser.PhoneNumber = $"12{i}6{i*3}{i*8}{i*9/3+2}";

                MerchandiserList.Add(merchandiser);
            }
        }
    }
   
    // Database commands and other logic not shown...
}
```

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**MerchandiserListPage.xaml & .cs** View - Display List of Merchandiers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MVVM.Views.MerchandisersListPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="MerchandiserListView" 
                      ItemSelected="MerchandiserListView_ItemSelected" 
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MerchandiserList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label
                                FontSize="Large"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                <Label
                                FontSize="Small"
                                Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


// MerchandisersListPage.xaml.cs - Code Behind
public MerchandisersListPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MerchandiserViewModel();
}

private async void MerchandiserListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Merchandiser merchandiser = (Merchandiser)e.SelectedItem;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MerchandisersProfilePage(merchandiser));
}
```

**MerchandisersProfilePage.xaml & .cs**
This page should navigate to the `MerchandiserEditPage` using an Edit Button but I'm not sure if I am handling  the 'Code Behind' correctly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MVVM.Views.MerchandisersProfilePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>   
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Name: " />
                <Label
                FontSize="Large"
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
            
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="PhoneNumber: " />
                <Label
                FontSize="Small"
                Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Button Text="Edit"
                    Clicked="EditButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


// MerchandisersProfilePage.xaml.cs - Code Behind

Merchandiser selectedMerchandiser;

public MerchandisersProfilePage(Merchandiser merchandiser)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   selectedMerchandiser = merchandiser; // Is this what I should be doing? 
   this.BindingContext = merchandiser;
}

private async void EditButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Am I doing this the correct way??
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MerchandiserEditPage(selectedMerchandiser));
}
```

**MerchandiserEditPage.xaml & .cs** This is where I am stuck.

I will need to update the record in the database by calling a method in the `MerchandiserViewModel` but am not sure how to do this?  The method (which ideally should be called by a `Command`) to update the database has the following signature `UpdateMerchandiser(Merchandiser merchandiser)`.

Ideally I would like the `Save Button` to use a `Command` instead of `Clicked` so I can access the Save command in the `MerchandiserViewModel` but this imposes another problem around form validation.  How then can I then validate this information (e.g. Name is not empty) before saving it the the database?  Because the `MerchandiserViewModel` doesn't know anything about the `MerchandiserEditPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MVVM.Views.MerchandiserEditPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Name: " />
                <Entry
                FontSize="Large"
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="PhoneNumber: " />
                <Entry
                FontSize="Small"
                Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Ideally this should use 'Command' instead of 'Clicked' -->
            <Button Text="Save"
                    Clicked="SaveButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


// MerchandiserEditPage.xaml.cs - Code Behind
public MerchandiserEditPage(Merchandiser merchandiser)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.BindingContext = merchandiser;
}

// I would prefer not to use an event handler but use a Command in the MerchandiserViewModel instead
// I also need to perform some basic validation e.g. Name entry should not be empty etc.
private async void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // How can I Save/Update the changes? 

    // Pop() page off the stack and return to the MerchandiserProfileView
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

I believe the above code is designed in accordance to MVVM, however if not, please advise where I am violating this pattern?

I also want to do similar for deleting a record but once I get the update method sorted I'm sure deleting will follow similar logic.

**Note:** The code above is not shown in its entirety and is missing SQLite database functionality and other logic for simplicity. All functionality to the database (Save, Update, Delete) is in the `MerchandiserViewModel`.  I will edit or add any additional information to this question as required to help provide a complete picture of the problem.

Comment: you've asked multiple questions so it's difficult to provide a concise answer.  First, there are numerous examples of Xamarin CRUD apps out there, you might want to look at a couple.  Second, if you want to follow MVVM then MerchandiserEditPage should have it's own VM that is responsible for validating the input before saving.

Comment: If I understand correctly, to comply with MVVM each `View` needs its own `ViewModel`?   How will the `MerchandiserProfilePage` know what Merchandiser was selected from the `MerchandiserListPage` if I'm binding to a new `MerchandiserProfileViewModel`?     How can I access Database functionally currently in the `MerchandiserViewModel`?  Using my existing code are you able to provide a code for what your suggesting as I have looked online for examples, but there is always some piece of the puzzle missing.

Comment: MVVM is a design pattern, please do not tie yourself in knots trying to "comply" with it.  Your VM can accept the selected Merchandiser as a parameter.  Your DB functions should be in a service/data layer, not in each VM.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/

Comment: Ok, I feel like I'm starting to understand a bit better.  If I understand correctly, I should pass the Selected `Merchandiser` to `ViewModels` and store my database logic in folders labeled "Service" or "Data".   Should each ViewModel inherit this logic?  e.g. `public class MerchandiserProfileViewModel : MerchandiserData {}`

Comment: instead of `this.BindingContext = merchandiser;` do `this.BindingContext = new MerchandiserProfileViewModel(merchandiser);`  Then that VM can have additional methods/properties for validation, etc.  Your VM doesn't need to inherit from a data class.  I would typically just have a static data class, or have it attached to my App class, so that it is accessible throughout the app.

Comment: Things are starting to click into place...  One last question before I implement your answer, you mentioned attaching the database functionality to the App class, are you referring to adding a Static Resource?

Comment: no, see step #3 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/local-database/?tabs=vswin&tutorial-step=2) where they add their DB class as a property of the App class.